# changing color on a cocos2d CCLabel

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a mutable array of CCLabels.  When I create the array of labels, I set the color of the label to black using:

```
label.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
```

At various points I want to change the color of a given label.

I've tried the following method, without success.

```
    -(void)updateLabel:(CCLabel*)l{
        [l setColor: ccc3(1.0,1.0,0.0)];
  }
```

I know I have a valid pointer to the label because if I change the method to

```
[l setString:@"test"];
```

It correctly changes the labels.  But the color doesn't change.  I don't see anything in the documentation to suggest the color is immutable once set.  So does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take floats, it takes byte values. So the following will work:

```
label.color = ccc3(255, 255, 0); 

or 

[label setColor: ccc3(255, 255, 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the documentation for `CCLabel`'s superclass, `CCSprite`, you will see this:

Line **144**: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/_c_c_sprite_8h_source.html

[image]

Which means that once an object is created, you cannot set the `color`, it is strictly readonly.

Comment: it works in newer cocos versions just fine (but takes byte values)

Answer (score -1):

```
//create Label like this
CCLabelBMFont *lblInfo = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Multi Color Label" fntFile:@"SSPro.fnt"];

then, you can Access the character using Index path.

  for (i=starting index; i<ending index; i ++) {

        CCSprite *charSprite = (CCSprite *)[[lblInfo children] objectAtIndex:i];
        charSprite.color = [CCColor redColor];
    }
set or change the color of character.
```